# Creating a shared key with a OneToOne Mapping and other issues

Tags: hibernate, jpa-2.0, eclipselink

I am trying to do something that seems simple but I can't figure out. I am using JPA2 and hibernate but I would like a solution that could also work with another provider like EclipseLink but that is a secondary concern.

I have a credential table that just has a password hash, a salt, and a user id.
I have a user table with some user data.

Here are my requirements:

1. Every user must have one credential, so it is one-to-one.
2. The app only needs the credential for creating a user and logging in
3. Many other objects contain users (i.e. invoices, history, address, etc) and I do not want those to indirectly load credentials every time I operate on them.
4. I want a credential to be automatically cleaned up when a user is cleaned up.

So here is my first attempt:

```
@Entity
public class Credential {
    @Id
    private Long id;

    @MapsId
    @OneToOne( optional = false ) // Btw, I don't care if this is lazy loaded or not
    @JoinColumn( name = "user_id" )
    private User user;

    ...

    public Credential( User user, String password ) {
       this.user = user;
       // set salt and hash from password
}

@Entity
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @OneToOne( optional=false, mappedBy="user", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY )
    private Credential credential; // this I do what lazy loaded

    ...

    public void setPassword( String password ) {
        credential = new Credential( this, password );
    }


User user = new User();
user.setName( "Charles Bukowski" );
user.setPassword( "b00z3" );

service.transactedPersist( user );
```

to this.

Okay, so now when I persist User can you guess what happens? Right, I get a data integrity exception on inserting the credential. That's because, yup, the user.id is set properly but there is no row yet in the user table. If I make credential optional=true it mysteriously works but I seem to get an extra update on User after a persist and all my queries that reference user now also query for credentials.

To be honest I wouldn't even reference a credential in user if I didn't need a cascade delete. If I were doing this without JPA that is how I would do it. I would set credential to be deleted each time a user was deleted but NOT have a reference in User for Credential. But with JPA I can only ensure that Credential is cleaned up if I add a attribute to it in User.

Anyway, the requirements are the important part so if you think I should be using a different design to achieve this I'm totally open to a better one. :)

I honestly wish JPA had the ability to use "references" as fields. Most of my objects that use User really only need his unique id. But I seem to load him AND the credential (and other OneToOne mappings in User) each time I read a referring entity.

Thanks in advance,

Oh, I think the answer to some of this might be to use byte-code instrumentation with lazy loading. But I am using Spring with CTW and Intellij. So I can't really figure out how to make that happen when I am debugging integration tests in IntelliJ. So any pointers there would be great.

Comment: Your entities look fine from what I can tell.  Try marking the Credential.user relationship as the id instead of using mapsid and see what happens.  You might try having credential use a diff id field just to see if the mapping is processed differently

Comment: Yup, I haven't tried it yet with EclipseLink but with Hibernate I get that batch insert exception. I suppose it is because they are non-optional on both sides. For Hibernate I can fix both of these issues by changing the OneToOne to a OneToMany and ManyToOne. Lame but it seems to work with lazy fetching and solves the non-existent User ID issue.